# Subset MULTIPLE specific rows and columns to update cell value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Onset = [17,18,19,20,21]
    Event = ['ArrowsTask', 'SelfReframeNeg', 'Memory', 'SocialReframeNeg', 'Cue']
    Response = [1,2,3,4,5]
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Event':Event,'Onset':Onset, 'Response':Response})
```

If`Event` == 'ArrowsTask', 'Memory' or 'Cue', I want to change the `Response` values in those rows to np.nan .

How can I subset the dataframe and achieve this goal?

The final df should be:

```
    Onset = [17,18,19,20,21]
    Event = ['ArrowsTask', 'SelfReframeNeg', 'Memory', 'SocialReframeNeg', 'Cue']
    Response = [0,2,0,4,0]
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Event':Event,'Onset':Onset, 'Response':Response})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That can be done by doing the following:

```
conditions = df['Event'].isin(['ArrowsTask', 'Memory', 'Cue'])
df.loc[conditions, 'Response'] = np.nan
```